# How to solve 3 linear first order equations using diagonalization when the eigenvalues are complex: An example

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, diagonalization

Given the following set of equations
\begin{equation}
\dot{X}(t) = M X(t) =  \begin{pmatrix}
                 -A/2   &  0  &  0\\
                   0    &  - A/2  & B\\
                   0    &  -B  &  -A  
              \end{pmatrix}
                  X(t)
\end{equation}
where $A$ and $B$ are constants, and $X(t) = \begin{pmatrix} x_1(t)\\ x_2(t)\\ x_3(t) \end{pmatrix}$. How can this system of equations be solved using diagonalization of $M$, since the eigenvalues of $M$ turn out to be complex, $m_1 = -A/2$, $m_{\pm} = -3A/4 \pm i K.$ where $K = \sqrt{B^2 - (A/4)^2}$. Assume the initial conditions as $x_1^0,x_2^0,x_3^0$.

Comment: What would you do if this were a system of two equations with two unknown functions and the coefficient matrix turned out to have complex eigenvalues?

Comment: I just gave it a try. I computed the matrix P from the eigenvectors of M. It turns out that P^{-1}MP is diagonal but PMP^{-1} is not. However, I get my desired solutions from the later condition.